# Drag and drop items to hidden div is not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

There are two divs overlaps one by other. One is for canvas. So its need to be active. Other div needs to be droppable. So I created it above and made it hidden. But now this droppable div not detects drop events. Can anyone help me to get out of this situation.

[here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hydride/j7ud8gLk/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="drop" id="drop">

  </div>
  <div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <h1>
    I need this area to be usable for canvas.So above div is hidden.
    </h1>  
  </div>
</div>
<div style="margin:0 auto; clear:both;overflow:hidden;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>

var $drop = $('#drop');
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img').draggable({
     revert: true,
     helper: 'clone',
     appendTo: 'body',
     containment: 'document',
     refreshPositions: true
   });
  $drop.droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('#drop').append(ui.draggable);
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        },
        deactivate: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});

.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  postion:relative;
}
.drop {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background:transparent;
}
.canvas-wrapper {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:none;
    border:1px solid #000000; 
}
.active {
  background-color:#FFF;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem lies in how the HTML engines render your content in the DOM. If you set the `.drop` to `display: none`, it will report its size as `0`, since it really doesn't take up any visible space.

Try to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display:none`

**[A Demo for you](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/j7ud8gLk/4/)**

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your 'drop' css class, remove the display:none rule.  Like this:

```
.drop {
    position: absolute;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background:transparent;
}
```

The background is already transparent, so you do not need a display:none rule.

Here is a jsFiddle:

[www.jsfiddle.net/hydride/j7ud8gLk/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/hydride/j7ud8gLk/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case when div is hide i have apply this code

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "destroy" );
```

when div is show i have apply again

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable();
```